# Array Formula not counting correctly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have one array formula which is behaving differently to all of my others.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/150rfbeuUW9RuG-iX6EGZAP83iOGr0KG_pn1ts-SXKoU/edit?usp=sharing

I just can't get 'Country Rating'!H2 to return the results I want and for some reason isn't counting the data in D:D correctly. 'Country Rating'!J2 is almost identical and seems to be working fine. I've narrowed it down to being an issue relating to the last "-" in the H2 formula but can't get any further.

I'm sure this is a very basic thing that I'm missing but it's driving me mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use those regex  `matches '.*Vegetarian.*'` and  `matches '.*Vegan.*'` as `matches` returns true only in case of a full match.

Also `.*Vegan*` was missing `.` before the last `*`, meaning zero or more `n` chars at the end.

And be aware that regex in `matches` is case sensitive and flags do not work there: you cannot use this `(?i).*vegan.*` for example.